# Change import path of Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have created a java library which has the following package structure.

```
├── src
     └── main
          └── java
                └── com
                     └── example...
```

The project is build using maven, and when i use it as a dependency in my other applications the import path is this:

`import main.java.com.example.....`, but what i'm looking for is this `import com.example.....` Any way i can change this?

Comment: for your java library using maven, your source folder should be: src/main/java, then everything in java folder will be the start of your package... if you are using the IDE like intellij, you should be able to specify the source folder in your project structure..

Comment: Is there maybe some definition in your POM that changes the source folder?

Comment: I rebuild the library with another version, and now the imports are correct. Not sure what changed

Answer (score 1):

Its not really clear what you're asking

From ***maven's*** point of view:

- The package structure you've presented is correct
- Maven packages the binaries created from the source code of your library into the jar that is not supposed to have `main.java` prefix (open it with a tool like winrar/winzip and see yourself)

So I conclude that your library is ok.

Now the imports in **your other applications** are wrong, so you have to change them. If you're asking about the actual way to change - the search and replace (and then recompile to get rid of compilation errors) on these applications should be done. The technical way of doing it depends on the IDE you're using.

For example, in IntelliJ: Ctrl+Shift+R